# weird takeUntil behave in rxjs 6

Tags: reactjs, rxjs6

First, the start button is stopped, then click restore01 button and restore02 button the start button restored,

then the bug is when click stop button01 or stop button02 then the stop button should be stopped, but not

notice console.log, the start button is stopped when start, then you click restore01 and restore02, then the start button works, and now the bug is coming like winter, when I click stop01 button or stop02 button, in console.log it show stop stream Array [ "r", "" ] but the start button still works, not be stopped, can you image my feeling about see this circumstances? oh my god

[online demo](https://codepen.io/dxcqcv/pen/QZBEqJ?editors=1010)

the code is blow

```
const startDom = document.querySelector("#start")
const numberDom = document.querySelector("#number")
const restoreDom01 = document.querySelector("#restore01")
const stopDom01 = document.querySelector("#stop01")
const restoreDom02 = document.querySelector("#restore02")
const stopDom02 = document.querySelector("#stop02")

let init01 = false
let init02 = false

const origin01$ = new rxjs.Subject()
const origin02$ = new rxjs.Subject()

const restore01$ = rxjs.fromEvent(restoreDom01, "click")
restore01$.subscribe(() => origin01$.next("r"))
const stop01$ = rxjs.fromEvent(stopDom01, "click")
stop01$.subscribe(() => origin01$.next(""))

const restore02$ = rxjs.fromEvent(restoreDom02, "click")
restore02$.subscribe(() => origin02$.next("r"))
const stop02$ = rxjs.fromEvent(stopDom02, "click")
stop02$.subscribe(() => origin02$.next(""))

const [stopReg$, right$] = rxjs
.combineLatest(origin01$, origin02$)
.pipe(rxjs.operators.partition(arr => arr.some(isEmpty)));
const restoreReg$ = right$.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.take(1),
  rxjs.operators.repeatWhen(() => stopReg$)
);


const start$ = rxjs.fromEvent(startDom, "click");
start$
  .pipe(
  rxjs.operators.mapTo(1),
  rxjs.operators.scan((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0),
  rxjs.operators.takeUntil(stopReg$),
  rxjs.operators.repeatWhen(() => restoreReg$)
)
  .subscribe(x => (numberDom.innerHTML = x));


stopReg$.subscribe(x => console.log("stop stream", x));
restoreReg$.subscribe(x => console.log("restore stream", x));

origin01$.next("")
origin02$.next("")

function isEmpty(n) {
  return n === "";
}
```

may be it's not very clear, so I tell you the steps

1. click 2 restore button, one by one
2. click start button, you'll see the number be added one after clicked
3. click stop button, OK, this is a problem, for now start button should be stopped, but not, you still can add one to click start button, but in console you can see the stop stream is subscribed, so weird

[I also have other demo with the same problem using react and rxjs](https://codepen.io/dxcqcv/pen/BqVGJP?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be with how you're using `combineLatest` and `Subject`.

`combineLatest(origin01$, origin02$)`

Where `origin01$` and `origin02$` are both a `Subject`. Subjects do not naturally hold onto old values to emit, they are in essence just "event emitters", they will broadcast their emission to subscribers and that's all, after that emission they don't hold onto it.

It looks like when `origin01$` fires, `combineLatest` is having to wait for the other Subject to fire again too before it will emit a signal. Your `stopReg$` stream might not be firing as you expect it to, check it with a `tap` like this:

```
rxjs.operators.repeatWhen(() => 
  stopReg$.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(x => console.log('got to here'))
  )
)
```

The `BehaviorSubject` could help here. Here's the description from the [RxJS docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject):

> A variant of Subject that requires an initial value and emits its
>   current value whenever it is subscribed to.

If you switch the origin `Subject` for `BehaviorSubject` instead, you might get the expected result you are hoping for. I tried this:

```
const origin01$ = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject("")
const origin02$ = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject("")
```

After I hit just one of the "stop" buttons, I was not able to see the "start" scan stream continue to sum values as I clicked on it.

I believe this worked because in the `combineLatest` since it was a `BehaviorSubject` instead, it was already able to grab the latest values and not have to wait for an additional emission from the other `Subject`.

Comment: but I still have a little question is when stopReg$ stream might not be firing, why stopReg$.subscribe(x => console.log("stop stream", x)); will be firing?